# How does the expression *++ptr is different from ++*ptr?

Tags: c, pointers, increment, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

Can somebody explain why in the output `3 4 4` is getting printed instead of `4 4 4`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int a[] ={0,1,2,3,4};
    int *p[] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int **ptr= p; 

    ptr++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
    *++ptr;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
    ++*ptr;
    printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Are you incrementing `ptr`, or what it points to?

Comment: See also [question 4.3](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/unopprec2.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Please copy paste the text don't use image

Answer (score 5):

For starters pay attention to that a difference of two pointers has the type `ptrdiff_t`. You may not use the conversion specifier `%d` with  objects of this type. You have to use `%td`. As for example

```
printf("%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

> How does the expression *++ptr is different from ++*ptr?

This expression

```
*++ptr
```

is equivalent to

```
*( ++ptr )
```

that is at first the pointer is incremented and points to the next element of an array and then it is dereferenced providing an lvalue of the pointed element.

This expression

```
++*ptr
```

that is equivalent to

```
++( *ptr )
```

that is at first the pointer is dereferenced providing an lvalue to the pointed element and then the element itself is incremented.

As for the shown code

```
   int a[] ={0,1,2,3,4};
   int *p[] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
   int **ptr= p; 

   ptr++;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
   *ptr++;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
   *++ptr;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
   ++*ptr;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

then initially the pointer `ptr` points to the first element of the array `p`.

```
   int **ptr= p;
```

then the pointer is incremented

```
   ptr++;
```

and now it points to the second element of the array `p`.

As a result this expression

```
ptr-p
```

yields the number of elements between the two pointers `ptr` and `p` (in this expression the array designator is converted to a pointer to its first element) that is equal to `1`.

As `ptr` points to the element with the value a + 1 of the array `p` then the expression

```
*ptr-a
```

also yields the value `1`. And the expression

```
**ptr
```

yields the value of the expression `a[1]`.

This expression-statement

```
*ptr++;
```

in fact is equivalent to

```
ptr++;
```

because the dereferencing of the pointer does not have a side effect.

Now the pointer points to the third element of the array `p`. And this statement

```
 printf("%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

outputs

```
2 2 2
```

Again this statement

```
   *++ptr;
```

is equivalent to the statement

```
   ++ptr;
```

because the dereferencing does not have a side effect. Now the pointer points to the forth element of the array `p`.

And this statement

```
   printf("%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

outputs

```
3 3 3
```

In this statement

```
   ++*ptr;
```

there is incremented the element of the array `p` (the forth element) pointed to by the pointer `ptr`. That is the forth element of the array is now equal to `a+4`

So the array `p` now looks like

```
int *p[] = { a, a + 1, a + 2, a + 4, a + 4 };
```

So this statement

```
   printf("%td %td %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

outputs

```
3 4 4
```

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm in writing a custom answer, but there *had* to be a duplicate for this one. ;-) Sorry.